# OrientDB/PhpOrient get users from a user with edge

Tags: php, sql, orientdb

Currently I have 3 classes in my Schema; `User`, `Thread` and `IsMember`.

Threads can have a edge to Users called IsMember meaning they belong in that Thread (chat app).

I would like to have all the threads a User belongs to. This is easily accomplished by using the following query:

```
select EXPAND(IN('IsMember')) from <@rid> limit -1
```

However this results in a array with Threads that have a reference to the IsMember edges in the `OUT_IsMember` offset. Instead of this I would like to have the `User` objects inserted in the `Thread` objects. Like this:

```
[
 {
   class: "Thread",
   users: [
    {
      class: "User"
    },
    {
      class: "User"
    }
   ]   
 }
]
```

Since there are a lot of records using a Traverse like;

```
traverse OUT('IsMember') from (select EXPAND(IN('IsMember')) from <@rid>)
```

simply wouldn't cut it since I would have to loop through the Threads/Users to map them which would take too long.

Since I am writing in PHP I am using the official driver https://github.com/Ostico/PhpOrient with this driver the Bag stays empty so the following query also wouldn't work;

```
select EXPAND(IN('IsMember')) from 12:589 fetchplan out_IsMember:2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract the users that are connected to a thread, which is connected to a given user, you can use

```
SELECT expand(IN('IsMember').out("IsMember")) FROM <@rid>
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually want to have those users you get with that query nested in the threads, or what would also be acceptable, the threads with the rid's of the users nested in them.

Comment: Try this query : select @rid as thread_id, out("IsMember").@rid as user_id from (SELECT expand(IN('IsMember')) FROM #12:0)

Comment: Excellent thank you so much! Gonna study that query to try and understand it a bit more so that I can also write such stuff. Thanks a ton!